# List all installed Windows updates - Programmatically in C

Tags: c, windows, winapi, windows-update

As stated in the title, I have to implement a program in C, that retrieves all the installed Windows updates.

I've seen I can execute a command like `wmic qfe get Hotfixid`, and just take its output, but not sure it's the most elegant thing to do.

I wonder if there is another approach to perform it in C. Do you have an idea?

Comment: use `system()` to execute any command, btw it is not recommended

Comment: @Darth-CodeX The point is I want to avoid using this kind of implementation.

Comment: Windows Update Agent API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wua_sdk/portal-client

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to [Searching for Installed Windows Updates](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6dba9cbb-4e59-4c90-9cf7-057f16f88078/searching-for-installed-windows-updates?forum=vclanguage). The case supplied two c++ solutions. One is *Windows Shell API* [FOLDERID_AppUpdates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/knownfolderid) and the other is *Windows Update Agent API* [IUpdateSession](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wuapi/nn-wuapi-iupdatesession) with *CoCreateInstance*.

Comment: Thanks for that! I must implement it in C. Can it be implemented in C?

Comment: You can use COM in C but you need the C style interface definitions.

Comment: @jtxkopt Can you elaborate a bit? What are those C-style interface definitions? Thank you!

Comment: You will access that API by using COM. In COM, the API is exposed to users in interfaces. You generally use C++ to access these interfaces since it is much easier than C and Microsoft doesn't always provide C-style definitions. An interface in COM, is basically a structure in which there is a virtual table. A virtual table is another structure which contains some bunch of function pointers to functions that the interface exposes. C++ hides this layout of data. You just access the interface functions as you call a C++ member function.